# Google OAuth Code does not include refresh token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-api

I want to make google api calls to send mail via gmail.

To do that, I first make the following request to oauth server:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=SOMECLIENTID&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63878/Default.aspx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

Note that in my request, I have included access_type=offline

It redirects me to POST https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser and I login using my account, give consent, and get redirected back to this page:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 06:30:37 GMT
Location: http://localhost:63878/Default.aspx?code=4/LF9pQo8EH-SZkkDJV0ttNnVMIwjwWLgnc-H-QjLg__k#
Content-Language: en
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

as seen on fiddler.

Now using this code, I make a second call:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 266
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: e9716588-2f62-d761-1c07-41c6dc057f0f
Accept: */*
X-Client-Data: CIm2yQEIorbJAQjEtskBCLKVygEI/ZXKAQjgmMoBCO2cygE=
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

code=4/LF9pQo8EH-SZkkDJV0ttNnVMIwjwWLgnc-H-QjLg__k#&client_id=SOMECLIENTID&client_secret=SOMESECRET&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63878%2FDefault.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response I get is:

```
{
  "access_token":"ya29.CjLzAuW07My8BHnaMaLWjhKsD2FvzI6SpUHqdqQwkugTW4lMnQl0rXt6cQdm0ir4RObYEg",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3557
}
```

Why does this not include the refresh token in the response?

Comment: and when you remove access_type=offline?  what language are you using to make the posts?

Comment: When I tried it again, in IE instead of chrome, it worked. Does it give out the refresh token only the very first time, and then stops on subsequent calls?

Comment: I was making calls using postman

Comment: Yes with Web applications you get it the first time only